# How to make while working with array?

Tags: arrays, while-loop

I just wanted to write a small program contains five generated random numbers.

I want my program to stop while "(tab[k]==tab[k+1])", but my statement doesn't work. Any help? :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {   
int i=0;
int k=0;
int tab[100]={};
srand (time(NULL));

do
{
    tab[i]=rand () % 6+1;//i=0..6..
    printf("Kosc 1 wynosi=%i\n",tab[i]);
    i++;
    printf("i1=%i\n",i);
    tab[i]=rand () % 6+1;//i=1..7..
    printf("Kosc 2 wynosi=%i\n",tab[i]);
    i++;
    printf("i2=%i\n",i);
    tab[i]=rand () % 6+1;//i=3..8..
    printf("Kosc 3 wynosi=%i\n",tab[i]);
    i++;
    printf("i3=%i\n",i);
    tab[i]=rand () % 6+1;//i=4..9..
    printf("Kosc 4 wynosi=%i\n",tab[i]);
    i++;
    printf("i4=%i\n",i);
    tab[i]=rand () % 6+1;//i=5..10..
    printf("Kosc 5 wynosi=%i\n",tab[i]);
    i++;
    printf("i5=%i\n\n",i);//}
    k=k+5;
}while(tab[k]==tab[k+1]);

printf("Kosc 1 wynosi=%i\n",tab[k]);
printf("Kosc 2 wynosi=%i\n",tab[k+1]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your code looks good. Try to debug it with printf("|%d : %d|\n",tab[k],tab[k+1]), maybe your tab[k] never be the same like tab[k+1].

Answer (score 0):

I made it working, but I used for instead of do...while. I'll try to figure something out later on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int i=0;
int k=0;
int tab[10000]={};
srand (time(NULL));

for(int s=1;s<1000;s++){    

    tab[i]=rand () % 6+1;//i=0..5..
    printf("Kosc 1 wynosi=%i\n",tab[i]);
    i++;
    printf("i1=%i\n",i);
    tab[i]=rand () % 6+1;//i=1..6..
    printf("Kosc 2 wynosi=%i\n",tab[i]);
    i++;
    printf("i2=%i\n",i);
    tab[i]=rand () % 6+1;//i=2..7..
    printf("Kosc 3 wynosi=%i\n",tab[i]);
    i++;
    printf("i3=%i\n",i);
    tab[i]=rand () % 6+1;//i=3..8..
    printf("Kosc 4 wynosi=%i\n",tab[i]);
    i++;
    printf("i4=%i\n",i);
    tab[i]=rand () % 6+1;//i=4..9..
    printf("Kosc 5 wynosi=%i\n",tab[i]);
    i++;
    printf("i5=%i\n\n",i);      
    printf("Kosc A wynosi=%i\n",tab[k]);
    printf("Kosc B wynosi=%i\n",tab[k+1]);

    if(tab[k]==tab[k+1]){

        printf("Numer proby=%i",s);
        return 0;

    }

    else
        k=k+5;
    }

    return 0;
}
```